# Is it safe to exclude libraries' assets (font in this case) from an Android Gradle build?

Tags: android, gradle

As the title says, is it safe to exclude libraries assets from an Android Gradle APK build ?

One of the Google's libraries is importing a font (~7mb).
Could this file be excluded safely to reduce APK size?

[image]

My current method to exclude files is to use an `ignoreAssetsPattern` statement:

```
android {
    ...

    buildTypes {
        ...

        release {
            ...

            aaptOptions {
                ignoreAssetsPattern '!NotoColorEmojiCompat.ttf:'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it safe to exclude libraries assets from an Android Gradle APK build ?

Generally speaking, no. The library is expecting the asset to be there.

If you feel that you have sufficient test coverage, and so you feel comfortable that you are not using the feature of this library that requires this asset, you're welcome to try excluding it.

IMHO, a better solution is to figure out what library this is coming from (my guess: Jetpack's Emoji library) and remove your code that depends upon it, so you can then remove the whole library from the project.

Comment: Using `./gradlew app:dependencies` I found what library was using the androidx.emoji package. Since I need this library I cannot avoid it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @EnzoCaceres: I think that there are a couple of different versions of the emoji library. The one you would appear to be using bundles the emoji into the app. I think that there is another one that downloads the emoji font. That keeps your APK smaller, but eventually that font will need to be downloaded.